# Accuracy issues with multiplication of matrices in Matlab R2012b

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix-multiplication, floating-accuracy, numerical

I have implemented a script that does constrained optimization for solving the optimal parameters of Support Vector Machines model. I noticed that my script for some reason gives inaccurate results (although very close to the real value). For example the typical situation is that the result of a calculation should be exactly 0, but instead it is something like

-1/18014398509481984 = -5.551115123125783e-17

This situation happens when I multiply matrices with vectors. What makes this also strange is that if I do the multiplications by hand in the command window in Matlab I get exactly 0 result.

Let me give an example: If I take the vectors `Aq = [-1 -1 1 1]` and `x = [12/65 28/65 32/65 8/65]'` I get exactly 0 result from their multiplication if I do this in the command window, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

If on the other hand I do this in my function-script I don't get the result being 0 but rather the value -1/18014398509481984.

Here is the part of my script that is responsible for this multiplication (I've added the `Aq` and `x` into the script to show the contents of `Aq` and `x` as well):

```
disp('DOT PRODUCT OF ACTIVE SET AND NEW POINT: ')
Aq
x
Aq*x
```

Here is the result of the code above when run:

[image]

As you can see the value isn't exactly 0 even though it really should be. Note that this problem doesn't occur for all possible values of `Aq` and `x`. If `Aq = [-1 -1 1 1]` and `x = [4/13 4/13 4/13 4/13]` the result is exactly 0 as you can see below:

[image]

What is causing this inaccuracy? How can I fix this?

P.S. I didn't include my whole code because it's not very well documented and few hundred lines long, but I will if requested.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: new test, by using Ander Biguri's advice:

[image]

**UPDATE 2: THE CODE**

```
function [weights, alphas, iters] = solveSVM(data, labels, C, e)
% FUNCTION [weights, alphas, iters] = solveSVM(data, labels, C, e)
% 
% AUTHOR: jjepsuomi
%
% VERSION: 1.0
%
% DESCRIPTION: 
% - This function will attempt to solve the optimal weights for a Support
% Vector Machines (SVM) model using active set method with gradient
% projection.
% 
% INPUTS: 
% "data" a n-by-m data matrix. The number of rows 'n' corresponds to the
% number of data points and the number of columns 'm' corresponds to the
% number of variables. 
% "labels" a 1-by-n row vector of data labels from the set {-1,1}. 
% "C" Box costraint upper limit. This will constrain the values of 'alphas'
% to the range 0 <= alphas <= C. If hard-margin SVM model is required set
% C=Inf. 
% "e" a real value corresponding to the convergence criterion, that is if
% solution Xi and Xi-1 are within distance 'e' from each other stop the
% learning process, i.e. IF |F(Xi)-F(Xi-1)| < e ==> stop learning process.
%
% OUTPUTS: 
% "weights" a vector corresponding to the optimal decision line parameters.
% "alphas" a vector of alpha-values corresponding to the optimal solution
% of the dual optimization problem of SVM.
% "iters" number of iterations until learning stopped.
%
% EXAMPLE USAGE 1: 
% 
% 'Hard-margin SVM': 
%
% data = [0 0;2 2;2 0;3 0];
% labels = [-1 -1 1 1];
% [weights, alphas, iters] = solveSVM(data, labels, Inf, 10^-100)
% 
% EXAMPLE USAGE 2:
%
% 'Soft-margin SVM':
%
% data = [0 0;2 2;2 0;3 0];
% labels = [-1 -1 1 1];
% [weights, alphas, iters] = solveSVM(data, labels, 0.8, 10^-100)


% STEP 1: INITIALIZATION OF THE PROBLEM
format long
% Calculate linear kernel matrix
L = kron(labels', labels);
K = data*data';
% Hessian matrix
Qd = L.*K;
% The minimization function 
L = @(a) (1/2)*a'*Qd*a - ones(1, length(a))*a;
% Gradient of the minimizable function 
gL = @(a) a'*Qd - ones(1, length(a));


% STEP 2: THE LEARNING PROCESS, ACTIVE SET WITH GRADIENT PROJECTION

% Initial feasible solution (required by gradient projection)
x = zeros(length(labels), 1);
iters = 1;
optfound = 0;

while optfound == 0 % criterion met    

    % Negative of the gradient at initial solution
    g = -gL(x);
    % Set the active set and projection matrix
    Aq = labels; % In plane y^Tx = 0
    P = eye(length(x))-Aq'*inv(Aq*Aq')*Aq; % In plane projection
    % Values smaller than 'eps' are changed into 0
    P(find(abs(P-0) < eps)) = 0;
    d = P*g'; % Projection onto plane

    if ~isempty(find(x==0 | x==C)) % Constraints active?
        acinds = find(x==0 | x==C);
        for i = 1:length(acinds)
            if (x(acinds(i)) == 0 && d(acinds(i)) < 0) || x(acinds(i)) == C && d(acinds(i)) > 0
                % Make the constraint vector
                constr = zeros(1,length(x));
                constr(acinds(i)) = 1;
                Aq = [Aq; constr];
            end
        end
        % Update the projection matrix
        P = eye(length(x))-Aq'*inv(Aq*Aq')*Aq; % In plane / box projection
        % Values smaller than 'eps' are changed into 0
        P(find(abs(P-0) < eps)) = 0;
        d = P*g'; % Projection onto plane / border
    end

    %%%% DISPLAY INFORMATION, THIS PART IS NOT NECESSAY, ONLY FOR DEBUGGING

    if Aq*x ~= 0
        disp('ACTIVE SET CONSTRAINTS Aq :')
        Aq
        disp('CURRENT SOLUTION x :')
        x
        disp('MULTIPLICATION OF Aq and x')
        Aq*x
    end

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    % Values smaller than 'eps' are changed into 0
    d(find(abs(d-0) < eps)) = 0;
    if ~isempty(find(d~=0)) && rank(P) < length(x) % Line search for optimal lambda
        lopt = ((g*d)/(d'*Qd*d));       
        lmax = inf;   
        for i = 1:length(x)
            if d(i) < 0 && -x(i) ~= 0 && -x(i)/d(i) <= lmax
                lmax = -x(i)/d(i);
            elseif d(i) > 0 && (C-x(i))/d(i) <= lmax
                lmax = (C-x(i))/d(i);
            end
        end 
        lambda = max(0, min([lopt, lmax]));
        if abs(lambda) < eps
            lambda = 0;
        end
        xo = x;
        x = x + lambda*d;
        iters = iters + 1;
    end
    % Check whether search direction is 0-vector or 'e'-criterion met.
    if isempty(find(d~=0)) || abs(L(x)-L(xo)) < e
        optfound = 1;
    end
end

%%% STEP 3: GET THE WEIGHTS
alphas = x;
w = zeros(1, length(data(1,:)));
for i = 1:size(data,1)
    w = w + labels(i)*alphas(i)*data(i,:);
end
svinds = find(alphas>0); 
svind = svinds(1);
b = 1/labels(svind) - w*data(svind, :)';



%%% STEP 4: OPTIMALITY CHECK, KKT conditions. See KKT-conditions for reference.
weights = [b; w'];
datadim = length(data(1,:));
Q = [zeros(1,datadim+1); zeros(datadim, 1), eye(datadim)];
A = [ones(size(data,1), 1), data];
for i = 1:length(labels)
    A(i,:) = A(i,:)*labels(i);
end
LagDuG = Q*weights - A'*alphas;
Ac = A*weights - ones(length(labels),1);
alpA = alphas.*Ac;
LagDuG(any(abs(LagDuG-0) < 10^-14)) = 0;
if ~any(alphas < 0) && all(LagDuG == zeros(datadim+1,1)) && all(abs(Ac) >= 0) && all(abs(alpA) < 10^-6)
    disp('Optimal found, Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions satisfied.')
else
    disp('Optimal not found, Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions not satisfied.')
end

% VISUALIZATION FOR 2D-CASE
if size(data, 2) == 2 
    pinds = find(labels > 0);
    ninds = find(labels < 0);
    plot(data(pinds, 1), data(pinds, 2), 'o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'red', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'black')
    hold on
    plot(data(ninds, 1), data(ninds, 2), 'o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'blue', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'black')
    Xb = min(data(:,1))-1;
    Xe = max(data(:,1))+1;
    Yb = -(b+w(1)*Xb)/w(2);
    Ye = -(b+w(1)*Xe)/w(2);
    lineh = plot([Xb Xe], [Yb Ye], 'LineWidth', 2);
    supvh = plot(data(find(alphas~=0), 1), data(find(alphas~=0), 2), 'g.');
    legend([lineh, supvh], 'Decision boundary', 'Support vectors');
    hold off
end
```

**NOTE:**

If you run the EXAMPLE 1, you should get an output starting with the following:

[image]

As you can see, the multiplication between `Aq` and `x` don't produce value 0, even though they should. This is not a bad thing in this particular example, but if I have more data points with lots of decimals in them this inaccuracy becomes bigger and bigger problem, because the calculations are not **exact**. This is bad for example when I'm searching for a new direction vector when I'm moving towards the optimal solution in gradient projection method. The search direction isn't exactly the correct direction, but close to it. This is why I want the exactly correct values...is this possible?

I wonder if the decimals in the data points have something to do with the accuracy of my results. See the picture below:

[image]

So the question is: Is this caused by the data or is there something wrong in the optimization procedure...

Comment: try changing the accuracy of the representation of the command window. try `format long` and then run it again. Most likely that is not a perfect `0`, however matlab displays it like that for you (because it is very close)

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri Thank you, I tried your suggestion in the command window. I added a screenshot. So there is no way of getting the 'exact' values?

Comment: `12+28 = 32+8` Equation is balanced. the correct ans is `0` Also when run in script i get the same answer. are you sure you are not copying the decimal values of `x` when you run the code in the script?

Comment: Hi @SanthanSalai the only two lines of code, where I modify the variable `x` are: `x = insol;` and `x = x + lambda*d;` where `insol` is a vector of zeroes, `lambda` is a real value of type `double` and `d` is a vector. P.S. `insol` is created with function `zeros`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the results you present as example. First of all: are you sure that all the numbers that you use are in `double` precision? MATLAB has this funny (and sometimes annoying) way of converting `double` to weaker precisions when mixing types (try `0.5 * int32(3)` at console to see what I mean). Most people expect the other way around.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/2917957

Comment: Thank you @CST-Link for your help. No I'm not sure of the precisions...I need to check that :)

Comment: @CST-Link What if I post my code here? Maybe you could try it as well?

Comment: P.S. I checked...all my variables contain class `double` values.

Comment: @jjepsuomi I use R2012a, and I cannot reproduce the non-zero result. Yeah, I'll run the code if you post it. It would be easier to trace. Hopefully it's not highly input-sensitive. :-)

Comment: Okay, I will try to clean it up and set up some comments with example of usage :) Thank you very much!! =) Wait for few mins ;)

Comment: @CST-Link Hi! I added the code now :) There are few example usages on how to use it :) P.S. the code isn't as optimal as possible, this is just my own testing x) The optimal solution for the example 1: is `X = [1/2 1/2 1 0]`

Comment: @CST-Link All the code needed should be there now. I added lastly also some visualization =) Please let me know if you get the same result as I do, I attached screenshots of what I get :)

Comment: You can also try the script with a random e.g. 2D data set (If 2D then you get a nice visualization ;) ). The data set must be LINEARLY SEPARABLE so that you can put a line between the two classes of clusters of data points. The data points in cluster one should have all label +1 and cluster 2 data points should have label -1

Comment: I see `inv` inside your code now, see my updated answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: @jjepsuomi Sorry, I was caught up a bit in something else. I'll try the code starting from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use `format` function inside your script? It looks like you used somewhere [`format rat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

You can always use matlab `eps` function, that returns precision that is used inside matlab. The absolute value of -1/18014398509481984 is smaller that this, according to my Matlab R2014B:

```
format long
a = abs(-1/18014398509481984)
b = eps
a < b
```

This basically means that the result is zero (but matlab stopped calculations because according to `eps` value, the result was just fine).

Otherwise you can just use `format long` inside your script before the calculation.

**Edit**

I see `inv` function inside your code, try replacing it with `\` operator ([`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)). The results from it will be more accurate as it uses Gaussian elimination, without forming the inverse.

The `inv` documentation states:

> In practice, it is seldom necessary to form the explicit inverse of a
>   matrix. A frequent misuse of inv arises when solving the system of
>   linear equations Ax = b. One way to solve this is with x = inv(A)*b. A
>   better way, from both an execution time and numerical accuracy
>   standpoint, is to use the matrix division operator x = A\b. This
>   produces the solution using Gaussian elimination, without forming the
>   inverse.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I do, in the very beginning of the script `format rat`. Thank you :) I will try your solution, by setting values less that `eps` to `0`. I tried the `format long` in the beginning of my script. Didn't improve the accuracy, still the multiplication was different from `0`

Comment: That is weird, and the result was this time in form of the long fixed-decimal format or still in the ratio form? What is the result now?

Comment: Yes, in the very beginning of my function I have the line: `format long` and the result I get now for the multiplication of `Aq` and `x` is `-5.551115123125783e-17`. P.S. I just now also tried: `Aq*x < eps` which returned `1`

Comment: I would store the result to another variable and compare `abs` value of that to `eps`, otherwise you will make the computation twice... Or if you just want to know if the result is zero, than this approach is fine.

Comment: Sry, I was unavailable for a while ;)

Comment: Replacing the `inv` with `\ ` unfortunately did not help enough :/ It actually gave a little bit worse result than `inv` in the Example 1 case...Thank you anyway =)

Comment: Btw I tried the original code in your question in my Matlab R2014b (64b) and it produces correct result (`0`), so I believe there could be some problem in your Matlab version also (do you use 32b? is upgrading to R2014b an option to you?).

Comment: Oh, nice to hear that =) Yes it is, I will try that :) Thank you!, I have Matlab R2012b, 8.0.0.783, 64-bit

Comment: Hi, In Matlab R2014a I get value closer to zero: `-1.110223024625157e-16`, which is smaller than `eps`, but not exactly 0. I can possibly also try with Matlab R2015a

Answer (score 2):

With the provided code, this is how I tested:

1. I added a break-point on the following code:

   ```
   if Aq*x ~= 0
       disp('ACTIVE SET CONSTRAINTS Aq :')
       Aq
       disp('CURRENT SOLUTION x :')
       x
       disp('MULTIPLICATION OF Aq and x')
       Aq*x
   end
   ```
2. When the `if` branch was taken, I typed at console:

   ```
   K>> format rat; disp(x);
             12/65
             28/65
             32/65
              8/65
   ```

   K>> disp(x == [12/65; 28/65; 32/65; 8/65]);
             0
             1
             0
             0

   K>>  format('long'); disp(max(abs(x - [12/65; 28/65; 32/65; 8/65])));
             1.387778780781446e-17

   K>>  disp(eps(8/65));
             1.387778780781446e-17

This suggests that this is a displaying problem: the `format rat` deliberately uses small integers for expressing the value, on the expense of precision. Apparently, the true value of x(4) is the next one to 8/65 than can be possibly put in `double` format.

So, this begs the question: are you sure that numeric convergence depends on flipping the least significant bit in a `double` precision value?

Comment: Hi @CST-Link no I'm not 100% sure. I just started to wonder this because in some examples (with some data set) I get the optimal solution whereas in some other case (with some other data set with lots if decimals in the data points) I don't get the optimal solution with this method. I will do some checking on my optimization procedure nonetheless, Thank you very much! =) The only way for me to be sure would be to do the calculations manually by hand, but that would take a lot of paper and time x)

Comment: You can try this with my code. First do the example 1 from my code. You should get graph with a line separating the data clusters and the line should be as "middle" as possible between the data points. Secondly create a 2D data set using `rand` function with two separate clusters with label values +1 for data points in cluster 1 and label values -1 in cluster 2. Probably in the second case the line won't as "middle" as possible between the data clusters. I made a hypothesis that perhaps the decimals could have something to do with this?...in the first case we have integer values for the data..

Comment: ...points whereas in the second case the data values can be for example 3.32546325543254543 etc.

Comment: see my post I added another pic, showing how the decision boundary is found with different data set.

Comment: @jjepsuomi I'm going to try a bit later, still at work right now, sorry... :-)

Comment: Of course no problem, take your time. Appreciate your help very much! Thank you :)